# Understanding JodaTime DateTime.parse(string, formatter)

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, jodatime

Does the style of the formatter in the [parse](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/DateTime.html) method of the DateTime class have to match the exact style of the string? For instance, I'm getting a TimeStamp object from the database (Oracle) and converting it to a string. In the database the TimeStamp is stored like this

> 08-AUG-12 12.00.00.000000000 AM

I set my formatter to this style

```
String pattern = "dd-MMM-yy";
```

I get this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "08-AUG-12 12.00.00 AM" is malformed at " 12.00.00 AM"

org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)

org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:144)
```

What exactly does this mean and how would I go about fixing it? When I set my formatter to  `"yy-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss aa"` I don't get an exception but it prints in the browser like this:  `2008-08-12T00:00:00.000-04:00`, but I need for it to print out as `"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss aa"`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use LocalDateTime instead:

```
String input = "08-AUG-12 12.00.00 AM";
String pattern = "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss aa";

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern));
```

**EDIT**

As a matter of fact you can do it with DateTime also:

```
private static String parseDateTime(String input){
     String pattern = "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss aa";
     DateTime dateTime  = DateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern));
     return dateTime.toString("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss aa");
}
```

Comment: when I  use `localDateTime.toString();` it still prints out like I indicated in the original message.

Comment: @Robert too late for the comment I guess :) you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. To get the correct format, you have to call formatter.print(localDateTime object) and it worked.

Comment: you also can specify the pattern to use in the toString.. localDateTime.toString("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss aa");