# How to find the date pattern from a date or timestamp string in scala

Tags: scala, date, datetime

Actually i want to find out the date format from a date or timestamp string .

Suppose if i have "12/2/2017" date string ,then the result should be "MM/dd/yyyy" .

Or if , I have "12-31-2017 10:12:00 AM" , the result should be "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss a" .

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166956/understanding-jodatime-datetime-parsestring-formatter

Comment: The dates can be in **any possible** format or do you have a set of possible formats? And how do you decide if **12/2/2017** is December 2nd or February 12th?

Comment: @Dr.Vick, no, it's not. This is about deducing the pattern from the string passed to you. It's not about using a known pattern

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar task yesterday. In some cases I will get as input "08.02.2017 14:00" and in other cases I will get "8/2/17 14:00". So I've come up with this util method:

```
def parseDateTime(datePart:String, timePart:String):LocalDateTime = {
    val dateDelimiter = if (datePart.indexOf('.') != -1) "." else "/"
    val dateFactors = datePart.split(dateDelimiter)
    val dayPattern = if(dateFactors(1).size == 1) "d" else "dd"
    val monthPattern = if(dateFactors(0).size == 1) "M" else "MM"
    val yearPattern = if(dateFactors(2).size == 2) "yy" else "yyyy"
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(monthPattern + dateDelimiter + dayPattern + dateDelimiter + yearPattern + " HH:mm")
    LocalDateTime.parse(datePart + " " + timePart, formatter)
  }
```

You should get the idea if read and reflect a bit over it.
In case of "08.02.2017 14:00" input the `datePart` and `timePart` input parameters will be "08.02.2017" and "14:00" correspondingly.
I need this since I parse two text fields in my automation code. Here is an example of usage:

```
def startDateTime(implicit driver: WebDriver):LocalDateTime = withMainWindow{
    val datePart = textField(id("dateRangeFormById[0].startDate")).value
    val timePart = textField(id("dateRangeFormById[0].startTime")).value
    parseDateTime(datePart, timePart)
  }
```